# How to use .htaccess rewrite to completely rewrite the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to imitate a routing effect. In my setup the login.php file is located under `localhost/session/login.php`. I've already found out how to omit the .php file ending but that's not enough for me. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This changes the URL to `localhost/session/login` but what I really need it an URL like this: `localhost/login`.. The trouble is that I don't really understand how the rewrite above works and I'm getting a lot of mixed answers.. don't know what to do exactly.

Is there a way to have my URL be `localhost/login` by using some RewriteCondition?

Comment: If you don't understand how rewrites work, then I'd advise you to familiarize yourself first with regular expressions (to better understand how patterns, like e.g. `^(.*)$` actually work in matching strings) and when you feel comfortable with that, read [Apache mod_rewrite intro](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use following rules in your site domain .htaccess to enable use `example.com/login` rewriting to `example.com/session/login.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/session/$1.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ session/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```